# variable doesn't print the expected value?

Tags: php

Here is my code. Database and tables are created successfully, but the thing is that when i try to echo the debug messages, which by the way contains status and error messages acquired while running methods and queries. when i try to echo it its printing 00. Not sure, but I think the problem may be with using `static` (but i want a static way) , i tried the code in in different ways on my own and after searching online with different keywords, found lot too but didn't help much.Now, The thing is I don't even know what to search for, wonder am i searching with wrong keywords? So i thought of posting here.

```
<?php
//creates required databases & tables

class Database
{
    public static $debug_message="";
    //root
    private static $host="localhost";
    private static $root="root";
    private static $root_pass="";
    //c db
    private static $user="c_user";
    private static $pass="c_pass";
    private static $db="c";
    //tables
    static $student="student";
    static $lecturer="lecturer";
    //field sizes
    const SMALL_TEXT=25;
    const MEDIUM_TEXT=50;
    const BIG_TEXT=100;
    const LARGE_TEXT=225;


    public static function CreateDatabase()
    {
        self::$debug_message+="CREATING DATABASE".self::$db." with user ".self::$user." password ".self::$pass;
        try{
            $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=".self::$host,self::$root,self::$root_pass);
            $dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `".self::$db."`;
                        CREATE USER '".self::$user."'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '".self::$pass."';
                        GRANT ALL ON `".self::$db."`.* TO '".self::$user."'@'localhost';
                        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;")
            or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(),true));
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            self::$debug_message+=$e->getMessage();
        }


    }
    public static function CreateTables()
    {
        self::CreateStudentTable();
        self::CreateLecturerTable();
        //echo for debugging
        echo self::$debug_message;
        return self::$debug_message;
    }
    static function CreateStudentTable()
    {
        self::$debug_message+="Creating Student Table <br/>";
        try {
             $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=".self::$host.";dbname=".self::$db,self::$root,self::$root_pass);
             $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
             $sql ="CREATE table ".self::$student."(
             student_id INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
             firstname VARCHAR(".self::MEDIUM_TEXT."),
             lastname VARCHAR(".self::MEDIUM_TEXT."),
             nationality  VARCHAR(".self::SMALL_TEXT."),
             enrollment_status  INT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);" ;
             $dbh->exec($sql);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            self::$debug_message+=$e->getMessage();

        }
    }
    static function CreateCourseTable()
    {
        self::$debug_message+="Creating Course Table <br/> ";
        try {
            $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=".self::$host.";dbname=".self::$db,self::$user,self::$pass);
             $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
             $sql ="CREATE table ".self::$course."(
             course_id INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
             course_name VARCHAR(".self::BIG_TEXT."),
             course_code VARCHAR(".self::SMALL_TEXT."),
             mqa_level INT(2));" ;
             $dbh->exec($sql);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            self::$debug_message+=$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    static function CreateLecturerTable()
    {
        self::$debug_message+="Creating Lecturer Table <br/>";
        try {
             $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=".self::$host.";dbname=".self::$db,self::$user,self::$pass);
             $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
             $sql ="CREATE table ".self::$lecturer."(
             lecturer_id INT( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
             first_name VARCHAR(".self::MEDIUM_TEXT."),
             last_name VARCHAR(".self::MEDIUM_TEXT."),
             nationality  VARCHAR(".self::SMALL_TEXT."),
             enrollment_status  INT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);" ;
             $dbh->exec($sql);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            self::$debug_message+=$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

//Tried two ways for debugging nothing works

//static way
Database::CreateDatabase();
echo Database::CreateTables();
//prints 00

//instance
$db=new Database();
$db->CreateDatabase();
echo $db->CreateTables();
//prints 00
```

Result

```
0000
```

But i expect it to print something like following

```
CREATING DATABASE c with user c_user  password c_pass
//if any error while creating database, that error message here
Creating Student Table
//if any error while creating student table, that error message here
Creating Lecturer Table
////if any error while creating lecturer table, that error message here
```

when i directly use strings inside and echo from the static functions the strings prints successfully but when i assign it to variable and tries to echo from main function of instance it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem actually has nothing to do with your use of `static` at all. Rather, the problem is that to concatenate strings in php, you use `.` and not `+`.

Instead of

```
self::$debug_message+="Creating Student Table <br/>";
```

You should have

```
self::$debug_message.="Creating Student Table <br/>";
```

An output of `0` is simply what happens when you [try to add two strings together](https://ideone.com/zsx8ny).

Comment: oh..how could i forget that.hehe..recently been on js,java and mostly on c#.. haha..i am now lol to myself :)  thanx alot..

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :P